# HTML form, file upload to google sheet or drive

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, frontend

I am trying to make a html form in which the user have to upload a file along with other details, I have successfully connected the form with a google sheet. But I am unable to connect the file upload section to the google sheet. I am attaching the app script which i have used to connect the form.

I want that the images that are being uploaded directly gets to the google sheet or in the drive with a link in the sheet, whichever will be possible.

here is the app script

```
        var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
    var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

    function intialSetup () {
      var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
    }

    function doPost (e) {
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
      lock.tryLock(10000)

      try {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

        var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
          return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
        })

        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }

      catch (e) {
        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }

      finally {
        lock.releaseLock()
      }
    }
```

```html
          <div class="containers">
            <form action="#" class="form" name="submit-to-google-sheet">
              <div class="input-box">
                <!-- <h2>
                    <center>Register Here</center>
                  </h2> -->
                <h4>Personal Info</h4>
                <input
                  name="Full name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Full name"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                <input
                  name="Phone no"
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Phone no"
                  required
                />
              </div>

              <div class="input-box address">
                <div class="column">
                  <input
                    name="State"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="State"
                    required
                  />
                  <input name="City" type="text" placeholder="City" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box address">
                <div class="column">
                  <input
                    name="Email"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    required
                  />
                  <input name="Linkedin" type="text" placeholder="Linkedin" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <br />
              <h4>Profession</h4>

              <div class="options">
                <input
                  name="option"
                  type="radio"
                  id="click"
                  class="hide"
                  checked
                />
                <label for="click">Student</label>

                <input name="option" type="radio" id="touch" class="hide" />
                <label for="touch">Working Professional</label>

                <!-- <input name="Profession" type="radio" id="love" class="hide" /> -->
              </div>
              <div class="input-box pro">
                <input
                  name="University/Company Name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="University/Company Name"
                  required
                />
              </div>

              <div class="input-box address">
                <h4>About Your Pitch</h4>
                <input name="Website" type="text" placeholder="Website" />
                <input
                  name="Linkedin of Company"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Linkedin of Company"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="input-box address">
                <input name="Idea" type="text" placeholder="Idea" required />
              </div>

              <br />
              <label for="images" name class="drop-container">
                <div class="info-icon">
                  <i
                    id="mytext"
                    class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"
                    data-toggle="popover"
                    data-trigger="hover"
                    data-placement="bottom"
                    data-content="Upload screenshot of you website or any product"
                  ></i>
                </div>

                <span class="drop-title">Drop files here</span>

                or
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="Files"
                  id="images"
                  accept="image/*"
                  required
                />
              </label>

              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <script>
              const scriptURL =
                "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jRX-yIQ5FUaZ3_zhZaetbkrAJTptD5riF-Qy1vt94ZI/edit#gid=0";
              const form = document.forms["submit-to-google-sheet"];

              form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                fetch(scriptURL, {method: "POST", body: new FormData(form)})
                  .then((response) => console.log("Success!", response))
                  .catch((error) => console.error("Error!", error.message));
              });
            </script>
          </div>
```

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. Where is your HTML put? Is it included in Google Apps Script project? Or, is it put to other server? 2. I cannot understand `I want that the images that are being uploaded directly gets to the google sheet or in the drive with a link in the sheet, whichever will be possible.`. If this is your expected result, can I ask you about the detail of it? 3. In your Javascript, it seems that you want to request to the Spreadsheet. In this case, can I ask you about the relationship between your Google Apps Script and your Javascript?

Comment: 1. Well I was following a tutorial on youtube, so i dont know how to answer this question
2. I mean that I want to have a upload filee section in my form and when the user(who is filling the form) uploads any image in that section, the image gets uploaded to my drive and a link to that image gets reflected to the spreadsheet, or the image can even directly be reflected in the spreadsheet.
3. In the javascript i have put the web app URL which i got after deploying the app script.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i have been looking for a solution everywhere and do reach out if you still have any problem in question..